# Calculating the maximum possible DPS in Elden Ring

Tags: elden-ring

You always see all these new builds posted on YouTube, but I'm wondering which specific build (including weapon, talismans and any buffs) will yield the highest possible DPS. Is this something that can be done mathematically and, if so, what specific topics would you need to create any sort of formula to calculate it?